# What is the best practical way to forward/redirect several hundred domains?

Tags: php, apache, hosting, dns, web-hosting

I want to redirect/forward several hundred domains each one of them to a special page on my main website ... for example, let's say I own business.com .. I want when someone try to visit any page on www.business.com will be redirected to the page www.mywebsite.com/business.com on my website.

As I said I want to redirect/forward several hundred and they go up and down in count all the time so it will be impossible to do it one by one. I want a solution more like how parking companies handle domains by pointing the domains to a DNS Servers like ns1.myowndns.com & ns2.myowndns.com and take it from there.

PS: I own a VPS using WHM Panel.

Looking forward to your replies.

Comment: use php to write contents to a .htaccess, or write a php script to interpret the domain and redirect accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Set up virtual hosting on your server
- Point the A record for all of your domains to your server
- Set up an explicit virtual host for (from the question) `www.mywebsite.com`
- Set up a default host to handle all requests to unrecognised domains.
- Put this .htaccess in the root of the default host:

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^.*$ http://www.mywebsite.com/%{HTTP_HOST} [L,R=302]
```

You could also place those lines in `<VirtualHost>` section for the default host if you want to keep your file system free of directories containing just a .htaccess

Comment: Thank you so much your answer. I have a couple of questions.

Comment: 1) You said "Point the A record for all of your domains to your server" that would be impossible since I told you there are hundred of domains and they will go up and down in count from time to time so if I setuped a DNS (EX: ns1.website2.com, ns2.website2.com) and pointed that DNS to my server IP would that solve this issue or you meant something else by pointing the A record of all my domains.

Comment: 2) Should a get another small VPS to handle all this other than the one than the hosting my www.website.com ?

Comment: 3) How will this system recognize which are my domains since anyone will point their domain DNS to my server will go through the redirection? ... Please forgive my ignorance since I'm not that experienced and I'll be doing this myself. Thanks again for your help and for your time.

Comment: 1) Whether you run a DNS server or not is irrelevant. Visit a web site via it's DNS name, the record that is retrieved is the A record. This is controlled by the name server (NS record) and if you run you own DNS server it may be *easier* to set up and maintain the A records, but you still need to create the A records, there is no way around that. Maybe you should do a little reading on the mechanics of DNS...

Comment: 2) There is no reason why you would need another server to handle this. All you other domain are simple HTTP redirects and the traffic should be minimal.

Comment: 3) Server will detect which DNS name was used to arrive at your server by inspecting the HTTP `Host:` header - which you can see in use above (`%{HTTP_HOST}`). The basic idea is that you set up the server so that when it receives a request for a domain it does not recognise, if creates the redirect. This means that you do not need to maintain a list of domains that you are forwarding on the web server, you just set up `mywebsite.com` on the server and forward every other to domain to it, as outlined above.

Comment: Thanks again for your continuing support. I'm a little confused here about the A Record. Based on what you said, if anyone set their DNS as mine and edited their A Record to match my server IP they will be easily redirected to my website.com ... I still can't figure out how my server will recognize my domains from others?